# Log Info in Event Viewer using Log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, event-viewer, log4net-appender

I'm currently working on a project where I want to log certain information in the Event Viewer using Log4net (EventViewerAppender). Logging with **Error** and **Fatal** gives me no trouble, but when I try to log with **Info**, it doesn't show up. I've checked my configuration and have looked all over the internet, but all I can find is people logging Info using a FileAppender.

I'm using the following configuration in my config file:

```
<log4net>

  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.Patternlayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline " />
    </layout>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <logName value="Services"/>
    <applicationName value="MyApplication"/>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
  </root>

</log4net>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any help would be helpful.

Thanks!
-dckwlff

**EDIT**

Seems I had it working all along, but was looking at the wrong view in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a LevelRangeFilter for appender:

```
<appender ... >
  ...
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="WARN" />
    <!-- FATAL ERROR WARN INFO DEBUG TRACE VERBOSE -->
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```